# Strategy pattern with inner enum

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, method-reference, functional-interface

I'm trying to get rid of big switch statement from my code and I thought that Strategy pattern based on my existing enum would be nice. The concept is like:

```
public class MyStrategy {

    public MyStrategy() {
        Option.Option1.setMethodToExecute(this::action1);
        Option.Option2.setMethodToExecute(this::action2);
    }

    public void executeChoosenMethod(int i) {
        Option.values()[i].execute();
//        instead of
//        switch(convertItoOption()) {
//            case Option1:...
//            case Option2:...
//        }
    }

    private void action1() {
        System.out.println("action1");
    }

    private void action2() {
        System.out.println("action2");
    }

    private enum Option {
        Option1, Option2;

        private InvokeAction methodToExecute;

        public void setMethodToExecute(InvokeAction methodToExecute) {
            this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
        }

        public void execute() {
            methodToExecute.execute();
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface InvokeAction {
        void execute();
    }
}
```

so I can use it like:

```
public class StrategyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStrategy strategy = new MyStrategy();
        //user choose 0 or 1
        strategy.executeChoosenMethod(0);
        strategy.executeChoosenMethod(1);
    }
}
```

but I don't like this part with `Option.Option1.setMethodToExecute(this::action1);` since my enum has more and more options and I would like to have all of this inside enum. What would be perfect is something like this:

```
public class MyStrategy {
    public void executeChoosenMethod(int i) {
        Option.values()[i].execute();
    }

    private void action1() {
        System.out.println("action1");
    }

    private void action2() {
        System.out.println("action2");
    }

    private enum Option {
        Option1(MyStrategy.this::action1), 
        Option2(MyStrategy.this::action2);

        private InvokeAction methodToExecute;

        private Option(InvokeAction method) {
            methodToExecute = method;
        }

        public void execute() {
            methodToExecute.execute();
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface InvokeAction {
        void execute();
    }
}
```

but this is impossible since enum is static and I don't have access to enclosing instance by MyStrategy.this. I need enum, because I have set of options and it is convenient to use methods like values() or valueOf(), but what I would like to have is single line invoke instead of growing switch.
Do you have any ideas how to achieve sometghing like this or is there any workaround to make this enum constructor call possible `Option1(MyStrategy.this::action1)` ?

Comment: Part of your problem is that `executeChoosenMethod(int i)` is a very un-OO method, and you're trying to use OO to model it. Passing the enum (or an interface) would be cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With enums you could implement it like this:

```
public class MyStrategy {
    public void executeChoosenMethod(int i) {
        Option.values()[i].execute(this);
    }

    private void action1() {
        System.out.println("action1");
    }

    private void action2() {
        System.out.println("action2");
    }

    private enum Option {
        Option1(MyStrategy::action1), 
        Option2(MyStrategy::action2);

        private InvokeAction methodToExecute;

        private Option(InvokeAction method) {
            methodToExecute = method;
        }

        public void execute(MyStrategy s) {
            methodToExecute.execute(s);
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface InvokeAction {
        void execute(MyStrategy s);
    }
}
```

This uses the fact the with lambdas you can make method references to arbitrary instance methods and call them on a specific instance by passing in the instance as first parameter.

Comment: Oh that is great, even better because we can use just Consumer<MyStrategy> instead of InvokeAction

Answer (score 0):

you're right. This isn't possible with enum. But why not just use a good old class:

```
public class MyStrategy {

    public MyStrategy() {
        buildUp();
    }

    public void executeChoosenMethod(int i) {
        actions.get(i).execute();
    }

    private void action1() {
        System.out.println("action1");
    }

    private void action2() {
        System.out.println("action2");
    }

    private List<InvokeAction> actions = new ArrayList<>();

    private void buildUp() {
        actions.add(this::action1);
        actions.add(this::action2);
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface InvokeAction {
        void execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I have methods like "printOptions" where Option.values() are very useful, I have control over possible values, I also use toString etc.